# what's the purpose of ssh-agent?

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-agent

I've read the official definition:

> `ssh-agent`  is **a  program to hold private keys** used for public key authentication (RSA, DSA, ECDSA).  The idea is that ssh-agent is started in the beginning of an X-session or a login session, and all other windows or programs **are started as clients to the ssh-agent program**.  Through use of environment variables the agent can be located and automatically used for authentication when logging in to other machines using ssh(1).

**"a  program to hold private keys"** - IMHO, ssh keys are generated by a user with the `ssh-keygen` command and simply stored in `~/.ssh` - why do I need some daemon to hold these keys? How exactly does it hold them anyways? - aren't they just stored in `.ssh`?

**"are started as clients to the ssh-agent program"** - I don't get it. Where would one need that? I usually just use ssh as this:

```
 ssh -i ~/.ssh/private_key_name username@hostname
```

What exactly does the above definition mean by "clients"? What clients? Don't you just run the `ssh` command from a terminal to connect to another machine? What other clients are there and why can't they just use the standard path to that private key file, just like the `ssh` command?

Comment: another benefit is that you may not have control over the call to `ssh` and cannot pass options regarding which key to use, and you may not want to add files to `~/.ssh`. Using `ssh-add` and some minimal bash statements you can add keys from environment variables and make sure they get used next time someone else calls `ssh` for you.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

The SSH agent handles signing of authentication data for you. When authenticating to a server, you are required to sign some data using your private key, to prove that you are, well, you.

As a security measure, most people sensibly protect their private keys with a passphrase, so any authentication attempt would require you to enter this passphrase. This can be undesirable, so the ssh-agent caches the key for you and you only need to enter the password once, when the agent wants to decrypt it (and often not even that, as the ssh-agent can be integrated with pam, which many distros do).

The SSH agent never hands these keys to client programs, but merely presents a socket over which clients can send it data and over which it responds with signed data. A side benefit of this is that you can use your private key even with programs you don't fully trust.

Another benefit of the SSH agent is that it can be forwarded over SSH. So when you ssh to host A, while forwarding your agent, you can then ssh from A to another host B without needing your key present (not even in encrypted form) on host A.

Comment: I feel this is the most complete answer, but there is still one point missing. Using a key agent also allows using multiple keys easily. Instead of having to specify the path to the key, when using a key agent ssh will try every key in it.

Comment: @Patrick which may also be it's disadvantage - try too many invalid keys on a server and it will close the connection before you got to the valid key. Of course, that's what `~/.ssh/config`'s `IdentityFile` option is good for, with or without the agent

Comment: @Patrick that seems equally possible without an agent

Comment: @AndreyFedorov Yes you can have multiple keys without an agent, but you can also specify in your `~/.ssh/config` which key to use for which remote host, so that it knows exactly which one it needs.

Comment: @Patrick since you can have multiple keys without an agent and since you can read ~/.ssh/config without an agent, it makes no sense to mention these when explaining the purpose of the agent.

Comment: so one can assume that `ssh-agent` is not necessary if a private key is not protected by a passphrase?

Comment: @pkaramol a private key without a passphrase is a security risk and for the most part `ssh-agent` is the *answer* to the security versus usability discussion that led some people to make passwordless keys. Assuming that the system memory is secure this is a much safer compromise. Aside from that, the other big benefit of `ssh-agent` is that SSH connections can *forward* the agent's socket along its connection, which can be enormously useful when you need to chain logins and `ProxyJump` isn't a viable option.

Answer (score 28):

The benefit to `ssh-agent` is that you only need to enter your passphrase once. If your private RSA key is not encrypted with a passphrase, then ssh-agent is not necessary. The `ssh` command would be an example of a client.

Comment: There are means of key protection beyond passphrases. ssh-agent can transparently handle those.

Comment: @ﾤﾡ perhaps, but I wasn't aware of them in 2013.

Comment: Could you please mention some of those methods? @ﾤﾡ

Comment: @r0berts Keys can be sealed using TPM. There are several libraries/tools for that. For Linux see [Protecting SSH keys with TPM 2.0](https://www.ledger.com/blog/ssh-with-tpm/). For Windows check [nCryptAgent](https://github.com/unreality/nCryptAgent/) or [A Better Windows 10+WSL SSH Experience](https://polansky.co/blog/a-better-windows-wsl-openssh-experience/). For low-level details on TPM see the answers on [TPM 2.0 PKCS#11 on Windows and Linux](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/126715/tpm-2-0-pkcs11-on-windows-and-linux/199687).

Comment: @r0berts Another direction which opens more options as concerns key protection is to use SSH certificates. See [If you’re not using SSH certificates you’re doing SSH wrong](https://smallstep.com/blog/use-ssh-certificates/) and tools like [PuTTY CAC](https://github.com/NoMoreFood/putty-cac).

Answer (score 14):

If you are routinely `ssh`ing into a variety of different machines, each with their own key and passphrase, then running `ssh-agent` allows you to enter the passphrase for each key once<sup>1</sup> at the start of your session and then you can authenticate to each machine as many times as you like without having to re-enter your passphrase.

A further benefit is that, as per the `man` page, the agent never sends a private key over its request channel; so if you are hopping between different boxes, your private keys are protected.

<sup>1</sup>You can set the `life` time that the keys are held in the agent.

Answer (score 13):

[Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssh-agent) probably has the best description:

> The verification to the server is based on challenge-response
>   authentication. ssh connects to the server with a user name and the
>   request for a key. The ssh daemon gets the request and sends back a
>   challenge based on the public key stored in the authentication file.
>   ssh uses the private key to construct a key response, and sends it to
>   the waiting sshd on the other end of the connection. It does not send
>   the private key itself. The ssh daemon validates the key response, and
>   if valid, grants access to the system. ssh-agent simplifies this by
>   creating a socket that listens for SSH connections. The user simply
>   starts ssh-agent, telling it how to find their keys (if they are not
>   in the default location), enters the passphrase for each key to be
>   used, on a one-time basis, and then ssh-agent handles the rest every
>   time the user connects to a remote server.

Again verbatim from the wikipedia article:

> ... ssh-agent creates a socket and then checks the connections from ssh.
>   Everyone who is able to connect to this socket also has access to the
>   ssh-agent. The permissions are set as in a usual Linux or Unix system.
>   When the agent starts, it creates a new directory in /tmp with
>   restrictive permissions. The socket is located in the folder.

It's typically put in either a system or user's rc files such as `$HOME/.bashrc` or `$HOME/.profile` (for bash shells) so that the environment variables `ssh-agent` set get incorporated into your environment completely.

On my Fedora 14 system it starts up pretty early as part of the X11 subsystem. In this file, `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc-common`:

```
# Prefix launch of session with ssh-agent if available and not already running.
SSH_AGENT=
if [ -z "$SSH_AGENT_PID" ] && [ -x /usr/bin/ssh-agent ]; then
    if [ "x$TMPDIR" != "x" ]; then
        SSH_AGENT="/usr/bin/ssh-agent /bin/env TMPDIR=$TMPDIR"
    else
        SSH_AGENT="/usr/bin/ssh-agent"
  fi
fi
```

The variable `$SSH_AGENT` is then made use in other X11 start-up scripts such as here, `/etc/X11/xinit/Xclients`:

```
exec -l $SHELL -c "$SSH_AGENT $XCLIENTS_D/Xclients.$1.sh"
```

By incorporating it into here, the following environment variables are getting set as part of a parent shell, therefore all forked children should also have them, for example:

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-PspRF18958/agent.18958; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=18959; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
```

There is a little more complexity to this but in a nutshell this is basically what's going on with `ssh-agent`.

For example in GNOME, `ssh-agent` is actually launch per user as a start-up application:

[image: ss of startup apps]

#### TL;DR

Bottom line, `ssh-agent` exists so that when your ssh keys are required you only have to unlock them one time with their passphrase (assuming they have one), and from then on they're available in their decrypted form in memory (RAM).

Answer (score 5):

"are started as clients to the ssh-agent program" refers to the idea that ssh-agent is started during (local) login session initialization so that all programs get the environment variables `$SSH_AGENT_PID` and `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` which are necessary for connecting the agent.

Another advantage of taking the private key handling out of ssh is that ssh-agent can be replaced by gpg-agent. Thus you can use OpenPGP keys (with authentication capability) for SSH. That's a nice solution for OpenPGP keys on a smartcard.