# pass an argument to a command which requires keyboard input

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a simple use case, I want to pass a password phrase to a command that requires keyboard input:

```
sshuttle -r user@server_address 0.0.0.0/0
```

this command will prompt for user input of sudo password of my Mac,

but I want to pass the password to it, instead of entering it everytime, I have tried:

```
echo "password" | sshuttle -r user@server_address 0.0.0.0/0
```

but not work, it still prompt for the password

Comment: If it uses `ssh` underneath, it should be able to use your SSH daemon that holds your private key. This is the standard way to do passwordless SSH. See e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30901 https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72552

Comment: no, it is not ssh password, it just requires my mac computer password

Comment: So you have not yet created an SSH key pair for logging in on the server?

Comment: You could try `expect` tool in some cases it should help https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/expect-examples/

Comment: The problem with passing a password this way is that it creates a huge security vulnerability in your system. An unprivileged user can see it and use it. That's why the other  comments are referring to using ssh which avoids this problem.